# Split google sheets into separate files

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace-for-business

I have a file with three sheets. I want to split the file in such a way that there are now three files with each file containing only one sheet.

Comment: The question is too broad. Are you looking to do this manually, using a macro or a script?

Comment: Apologies for wording the question broadly. Most of my colleagues are not computer frenziedly.  Hence the easiest method is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to make two copies and the delete two sheets on the original and each of the copies:

- Original

  - Sheet 1
  - Sheet 2 - delete
  - Sheet 3 - delete
- Copy 1

  - Sheet 1 - delete
  - Sheet 2
  - Sheet 3 - delete
- Copy 2

  - Sheet 1 - delete
  - Sheet 2 - delete
  - Sheet 3